# Spring Boot overriding my configuration with global configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application building with Maven.  It builds fine except on a single EC2 instance where something is made wrong with the fat jar.  Basically it will register beans in the wrong order so that Spring winds up overriding my custom configuration beans with the Global configuration beans and blowing away my security settings.

It's absolutely bizarre that this only happens when the jar is built on this machine.  I can build the app's jar on any other machine, Windows, OS X, Linux VMs running on Windows, maven running inside Docker containers, etc and those jars work fine everywhere--even on the machine that generates bad jars.  But jars from this "bad" EC2 instance will run with the error on every other machine, including those that generate good jars.

The actual error presents while the app is starting up, as Spring scans the classpath and registers bean definitions.

```
2017-03-31 17:32:33,362 INFO  [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory : 
Overriding bean definition for bean 'methodSecurityInterceptor' with a different definition: 
replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=methodSecurityConfig; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/my-app/security/MethodSecurityConfig.class]] 
with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=methodSecurityInterceptor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]]
```

My class actually extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration so Spring is replacing a child with its parent.

It seems like it defeats the point of using maven if the classpath order can go haywire by something as invisible as this.  I've already made sure it's using the same version of Maven on this server as the other machines, the same java version, and even went through the trouble of installing an Oracle JDK on that server to match the Oracle JDKs on the Windows systems.

Any idea what else could be making screwed up jars when I've ruled out OS, JDK, and Maven version differences?  It's the same code checked out from Git.

EDIT:  I was able to work around the issue, I think, by specifying that my config class which extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration also @Import(GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class) and that seems to force Spring to adjust the order.

As to why the difference exists, I'm still at a loss.  I had a theory at one point that differing zip implementations invoked by the Maven Spring Boot plugin during repackage created a zip filesystem with files in the wrong order but while the order of packed files WAS different, my classes still came before the Spring jars so I don't think that can explain.

Comment: Can you explaın a little more about the problem? Because I don't undertand if the produced jar file is different or in runtime you are experiencing different behaviour.

Comment: The produced jar is somehow different but whatever difference there is is somewhere in the compiled class files so it doesn't stick out.  The problem presents at runtime during startup, I'll update the question with more specific log messages.  But it's not a runtime environment issue because a jar from my local machine will run fine on that server but jars generated on that server run with the error on all machines.